# How to compare two tex file outputs?

Tags: pdftex, texmaker, overleaf, highlighting, latexdiff

I want to get a highlighted pdf where the difference in two tex files output is captured.
My main tex file calls separate tex files as chapters using  `\include` . I tried using latexdiff, but it is not highlighting any changes.

I also tried -

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpagediff}

\begin{document}  

\layerPages{pdf1.pdf}{pdf2.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Still no highlighted output. Please help.

Comment: you can also diff the pdf eg https://pdf.wondershare.com/pdf-knowledge/pdf-diff-linux.html (random google search result not a specific recommendation)

Comment: I use `diffpdf` on linux (debian or debian based). Try that. Recommended.

Comment: @koleygr It is asking for licence key. The key generated shows invalid.

Comment: @SandeepPandey ... What OS are you on?

Comment: @koleygr Windows 10

Comment: @SandeepPandey This https://alternativeto.net/software/diff-pdf/about/ is Open source and is supposed to work on Win too. So, if you get the same problem I suppose you can trust it.

Comment: Hmmm...somebody should build a diffpdf 2.0 appimage or flatpak to avoid that sometimes that stops working.